# How to create tables in dynamoDB dynamically using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Can I get example to create tables in dynamoDB dynamically using Hibernate hbm2ddl. I would be greatful Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DynamoDB is a NoSQL database (i.e. non-relational database). It doesn't come under RDBMS.

`hbm2ddl` tool cann't be used to create DynamoDB table. It can be used to create RDBMS tables in database such as Oracle, MySQL etc.